# InstallScript Custom action

Tags: windows, visual-c++, installation, installshield, installscript

I have created a dll c++ custom action that is creating a new dialog.
I am trying to start this custom action through installScript function and I am unable to.

I am sure this is easy. but I am new in InstallScript and I can't find any answer on the net.

Thanks!!!!
Ben

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution.

Define your custom action in Custom Action and Sequences (in the installation designer).
Then go to the script where you want to use your and use

```
MsiDoAction(ISMSI_HANDLE, "YouActionNameAsDefined")
```

Hope this was helpful.

Ben